# In HTML input how to skip nth space and take the rest of the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

example- abc vbn vcf bvg jng klm souro
say after 3 space i have to take the remaining text..how?
pls answer using jquery. Want the best way out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specifiy the output you want? And what have you done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following. Hope this will help you.

```
var your_string = 'a b c ddddd';
var result = your_string.split(' ');
result.splice(0, 3);

console.log(result.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the split and slice methods.

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  $('div').html(
    $('input').val().split(" ").slice(3, -1).join(" ")
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="width:120px" placeholder="enter some text with blanks" />
<br/>
<div></div>
```

```
  your_string.split(" ").slice(3,-1).join(" ")
```

split will divide the string where ever there is a blank space and give you an array, then slice will take out a 'slice' of the array (-1 means from the end) and finally join will put it back together inserting the blanks back in.

Comment: OP wants the text and not the array...!

Comment: my bad, forgot the join(" ") in my haste!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "abc vbn vcf bvg jng klm souro";
var newString = string.split(" ").splice(-4).join(" ");
alert(newString);
```